# why my pdf file do not open by default by adobe reader?

Tags: pdf

I download pdf files from internet on my laptop drive, when I double click on these file, they open in mozilla browser and not by adobe reader X in which I have installed. They can be opened by adobe reader if I right click on file and then select open with. I want that when I download pdf files, it should save as adobe reader file and should be opened by reader by double clicking on file. How it can be done?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: I am using windows 7 professional.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

Open With > Choose Default Program > Adobe Reader ? (For Windows)

Comment: It solve my problem. thanks, I have adobe reader X. When I take my pdf file to a shop for print, it did not open there. Is there can be problem that they have some other pdf?